# How many ways are there to tile an $m*n$ chessboard with infinite singletons and dominos?

Tags: combinatorics

**Flip and rotation are not considered.** When $m=2$,it is $OEIS:A030186$.It is a litte hard to calculate when $(m\ge3)$.I want to know if there exist a formula to caluculate?

The situation only to use dominos exist a formula to caluculate.(I find it in *"Statistical Mechanics of Dimers on a Plane Lattice"*,write by *Fisher Michael E.* $\qquad$ *Stephenson John*)

Comment: Confusing : We have a finite size of the board but infinite many stones ?

Comment: @Peter Sorry sir,I mean, there are “enough” singletons and dominos